# Proving/Disproving (via formal proof) pairwise distinction for conjoined cycles when each individual cycle is pairwise distinct

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, normal-subgroups

Lets suppose that X & Z are members of some arbitrary $S_n$ group and that X & Z are cycles. Then we define cycles X & Z by:

$ X = (a_1 a_2 ... a_m) $   - which are pairwise distinct members of $\mathbb Z^+$

$ Z = (b_1 b_2 ... b_n) $ - which are pairwise distinct members of $\mathbb Z^+$

-- Suppose that $ X \circ Z = Z \circ X $ , then must it be true that $ a_1, ..., a_m, b_1, ..., b_n $ are pairwise distinct?

Intuitively I don't think that they "must" be pairwise distinct since there could be overlap between what elements are in X & Z while they still satisfy their own constraint of being individually pairwise distinct

For X = (1 5 8 6 4 ) and Z = (2 3 7 9 1) are pairwise distinct in their own cycle, but when conjoined through their operation of composition they are no longer pairwise distinct since there is a repeating '1'. But I am having trouble formulating this into a formal proof that expresses this idea (assuming it is correct)

any and all help is appreciated

Comment: No because we could have $X=Z$ or $X$ could be a power of $Z$.

Comment: What you can say is that if $X\circ Z=Z \circ X$ then either $\{a_1,\ldots,a_m\} = \{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$ and $X$ is a power of $Z$, or $\{a_1,\ldots,a_m\}$ and $\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$ are disjoint.

Comment: You start out by saying that $X$ and $Z$ are disjoint cycles. What do you mean by this, if not what you're trying to prove, that their elements are pairwise distinct?

Comment: @DerekHolt thanks man!! showing their relation with the 'either... or...' made how the two interact/relate with one another a lot clearer, which definitely helps me prove it more precisely & accurately !

Comment: @joriki i see what you mean now lol and i apologize if that was contradictory/confusing, but what i meant when i said that they are disjoint was that they can work independently from one another, not that they were just two separate transpositions of one permutation

Comment: What does that mean, "they can work independently from one another"?